# Why do cats hate riding in cars?

Tags: behavior, cats, travel

Whenever we need to take one our cats in the car (usually to the vets, but not always), the in-car drama is quite intense with a yowling and even vomiting (rare for short durations). Why do cats, unlike dogs, hate riding in cars? Is there a way to make this a better experience for them?

Comment: Our cat hated to ride in the car, and would always defecate in his carrier during the car ride, no matter how short the ride.  Of course, the only place we ever took him in the car was the vet, so I figured that had something to do with it.

Comment: @BenMiller - Had that happen once too. On the plus side for that, it was to take him to the vets because he was constipated, so it saved us some money...

Comment: There are a few factors involved: (a) being in a carrier versus out; (b) being in something that's moving; (c) going to the vet.  Have you tried to isolate any of those variables?  (For example, have you tried a harness instead of a carrier?  This would involve a second person.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio - We've done those.

Comment: Why do some cats hate riding in cars, and some cats don't?

Comment: @EsaPaulasto - I think you'll find that cats that like are exceptions as opposed to the rule.

Comment: We have only one of our cats who regularly craps herself in the last quarter of a one hour long car drive, the rest of our cats take it easy. But you are may be right, perhaps they are exceptions all (even the crapping one is calm in a car, only gets motionsickness).

Comment: We had tried taking the cats out for rides just for the sake of getting out, specifically to dissociate the car with the vet. That didn’t really work. Even though they were never in a carrier (we never even had one), they would always climb down to the floor and try to burrow under the seat. Even holding them up to the window to see things didn’t appeal to them. I can’t help but wonder if maybe they are more sensitive to motion-sickness…

Comment: @JohnCavan The exceptions are great though;  we have a small Maine Coon who curls up on the seat and sleeps, or puts her paws up to the window and watches the scenery.

Comment: I don't really know why some cats do like it and some don't and if those who like are exceptions opposed to the rule as some of you have said. The only two cats from the many that I've had that have been in the car, liked the experience. Once my cat got in the car with me and wouldn't get out and I was late so I ended up taking her with me and she happily enjoyed her little trip to a studying center near by in the neighborhood to pick up my sister.

Comment: Took in a stray kitten about 5 months old and took to the vet same day and did not have any cat stuff so used a box no problem. Said to self ok this is going to be easy. Purchased a harness and leash and started putting on the kitten for a few hours each day with no problem. Fixed a box that could be strapped in with seat belt so she could sit and look out. A few weeks later another trip to vet. I secured her leash and this little girl sure did not act very happy but she sat on top of the box looked about the entire time or would lay down. This has been the most trouble free and sweet little k

Comment: It may be that cats experience sounds, vibrations, etc. of a moving vehicle differently than dogs do - perhaps even painfully. Last weekend, we took our motor home to visit our daughter who is away at college - and naturally wanted to take her cats along for the trip. We experienced the typical restless meowing when the cat was in the carrier, but once in the motor home, he seemed to calm down & curled up on the couch like cats typically do. Once the motor home was started, however, he became incredibly restless, meowed constantly, and sought safety/confinement under the passenger seat. Once a

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Anecdotally, I have to first say that not all cats hate riding in the car.  I've known at least one cat that was perfectly content to ride in the car.  This cat started as a kitten going for rides to all sorts of different places, which is probably directly relevant to what follows in this answer.

I believe that the main difference between cats and dogs in this regard involves differences in how the two species remember information.

While I was unable to find specific research covering this, my own experiences and some [insufficiently referenced articles](http://pets.thenest.com/cats-longterm-memory-8646.html) indicate that cats have the potential for some degree of long-term memory [that works in a fashion fundamentally similar to humans](http://www.vetinfo.com/how-cat-memory-works.html).

Dogs, on the other hand, seem to have generally [less ability to remember specific things or events](http://dogcare.dailypuppy.com/dogs-longterm-memory-2305.html).

Perhaps most relevant, though, is that cats have significantly better retention, both short-term and long-term, than dogs:

> Researchers have discovered that there is not much difference between how a cat, a human, or another animal’s brain utilizes certain cues to assist in the creation of short and long-term memories. A cat’s brain functioning has been compared to that of a two to three year old child and, when compared to a dog, a cat’s memory is almost 200 times more retentive. Without repeated and reinforced training, a dog’s memory span is about 5 minutes. Cats, on the other hand, averaged about 16 hours, only IF the activity benefited THEM.

[Source](http://www.critters360.com/index.php/feline-memory-retention-cats-remembering-cats-memories-short-term-memory-long-term-memory-21774/)

So unless the car ride to the vet, and the wait to actually see the vet, is less than 5 minutes, your dog probably forgot the series of events of:

1. Get in the car
2. Drive
3. Arrive at the vet
4. Wait to see the vet
5. Get poked, prodded, restrained, and possibly stabbed with one or more needles
6. Get back in the car
7. Go home

In particular, #4 generally provides a lot of distractions to a dog, such as a novel environment filled with new smells, or a variety of other pets also waiting.

Cats, on the other hand, seem to recall quite well that step 1, get into the cage, most likely leads to step 6, get poked, prodded, and possibly stabbed with one or more needles.

Certainly some dogs can, and do, form an association with car rides and going to the vet, but for most dogs a trip to the vet seems to be less frightening and unpleasant than it is for a cat (a cat is far less likely than a dog to look upon a room full of new smells and strange animals as a positive).

Furthermore, dogs are more likely to have travel experiences that don't involve a trip to the vet (e.g. a ride to the dog park, going to a pet-friendly pet store, hiking, hunting, or even on family vacations), and less likely to be confined to a cage during the ride (and of those dogs who do ride in a cage during a car ride, many of them have probably been specifically [crate trained](http://www.humanesociety.org/animals/dogs/tips/crate_training.html#.Up9vBNLBP4I)).

With regards to how you might improve the experience for your cat:

You can try to reduce the negative associations your cat already has with being in the car (and probably being put into a carrier prior to the car ride).  It is certainly easier to do this when they're young, before they've formed the negative associations (such as the kitten I mentioned earlier in my anecdote), but you may have some luck by taking your cat on "joy rides".

Start by bringing your cat out to the car, and let them explore (closely supervised! You don't want the cat to get wedged under a seat where you can't get them out) the car while it sits parked, with the engine off.

Do this every couple of days (or even every day), until the cat seems comfortable in the car.

Then progress to short trips around the block.

If your cat handles strange animals (particularly dogs) reasonably well, you might eventually try a trip to a pet-friendly pet store, but for most a nice quiet park where they can walk while on a harness would be a better choice.

Once your cat becomes accustomed to these pleasant (or at least, not unpleasant) trips, you should (hopefully) see a reduction in anxiety during car trips in general.

Comment: +1, I like this, but I suspect there is more to it than this. I suspect it is the motion of the car that makes the cat uneasy. Also, being put into a cat carrier can be unpleasant, I did have a kitten that was find in the car if she could sleep on my lap!

Comment: I agree, I think this is a big part of the story, but I don't think it's the whole story.

Comment: I think there's more to it, too, although it's an excellent answer. One of my cats as a kitten played quite happily in the car when it was parked and didn't mind one bit when he went into the car to return home (we got him while we were on vacation - or he got us). The moment the car started moving, he freaked out.

Comment: Adding to the anecdotal data, I have to say out of the 8 cats I've owned during my lifetime, only one could be described as freaking out during car rides (he never became sick, but he was normally aggressive, and car rides made him wild).  The other 6 would just sit there and meow piteously.

Comment: Cats can remember things for years. I know this. And I doubt the 5 minute thing for dogs.

Comment: Additional anecdotal: my previous cat was perfectly happy with car travel ... but she was allowed to roam around the car while in motion an had a lot more exposure to it since mom had a camper van and took the cat on trips sometimes. It may have helped that this cat had the classic 'Meezer personality, very focused on her humans, and if she was with us it must be ok... but I really do think that letting her get used to vehicles without being boxed, though more dangerous for her and needed strict training to keep it from being dangerous to the drivers, may have made the difference.

Comment: My own cat doesn't like to ride in the car. When he was younger, I tried to leave him loose in the truck on the way to the vet. However, after the first time he got nervous and peed, he had to be crated. He isn't crate trained and only gets crated for the vet. Therefore, he has to be stuffed into the carrier and pees every time. I do scrub it out after the vet visit. On the other hand. My cousin is going to school and hour away and frequently comes home. She found a street kitten and took him in. He's been traveling in the car very frequently and enjoys it. Often sleeping all the way home.

Answer (score 13):

I ended up discussing this with my vet one day (one of the girls had surgery and stopped eating, so we inserted a feeding tube to feed her until she started feeling better. We picked her up from the vet, got the feeding lesson, and went home. She puked on the way home, so we had to go back and make sure everything was still in place).

It's my vet's belief that cats don't process the motion of the trees and such well, and they do better if you place a towel over the carrier or arrange things so that they can't see out of the windows.

I think that this may be partially right, but also that cats get anxious for different reasons, and the best way to ease the trip for your cat is to determine what causes anxiety for your cat and treat that as best as you can.

For this particular girl, she gets anxious about being handled by people at all, and by unfamiliar situations. There wasn't much we could do except be as calm as we could be and take care of everything quickly.  Usually, when she isn't so ill, we try to combine her trips with one of the boys (they get along together well) and the presence of a buddy helps keep her calm.

We once had another cat who only ever wanted to be petted. He would cry and cry and cry and finally we would relent and whoever wasn't driving would let him sit on their lap and he was quiet and calm.

Our youngest boy is high energy and gets bored, so we try to give him a toy, or talk to him or distract him somehow, and that helps him.

These examples may or may not work for you, but they're examples of how we've looked at each cat's personality and tailored a plan to help each one.

Finally, for a longer trips or for extreme stress (the cat is harming itself) you can talk to your vet about sedative medications. Your vet should explain the risks and benefits of those medications.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are some great answers here, but I wanted to suggest one more thing. I believe it's simply because you expose your dog to much more than you do your cat. You take your dogs outside on walks, you take him on car rides to go fun places like the river, you introduce him to people in a positive way, etc...

With cats, they're usually kept inside, they're rarely ever taken outside in the company of people (excluding people who walk their cat on a leash), and they get to run off and hide whenever they come across a situation they don't like. Coupled with the fact that cats don't have nearly as strong a desire to be in a group and you can see where they're react very differently.

I think if any cat is exposed young and/or worked up to a situation slowly, they'd over come their fear. I think it's perfectly understandable that they get upset when they're stuffed in a crate, put in a loud moving vehicle, then put in a loud, smelly vets office, where they're only dragged out to get poked and prodded.

I suggest you'd do like you would with a dog. Get them used to a carrier in the house, by putting treats in it. If they go in, shut the door for a few seconds and increase duration over time. Pick it up and move it a few feet. Either leash your cat or if it's an indoor/outdoor cat leave your car doors open and put some treats on the seat. See if you can work up to getting him to stay inside if you turn it on.

I think you can see where I'm going with this. I believe it's mainly an issue of exposure, training, and expectations. My own cat, in his formative years, was living in a house that didn't allow cats, so when the landlord came over, all his stuff got put in a closet and he was shut in a back bedroom, now at 11yrs old, he hides when anyone comes over unless he's seen them half a dozen times. On the other hand. I was at a party once that was obnoxiously loud, with people smoking, drinking, and yelling and a cat came out rubbing on peoples legs and hopping in their laps. Other people have cats that ride across the country with them in their RVs.

Comment: Also, dogs by their nature are accustomed to moving about the country with their pack, seeing what's  around.  A dog pack is nasty enough to need fear little danger on these trips.  They hunt that way.  A cat, on the other hand, uses its detailed knowledge of its small home range to survive. A cat can be killed by a larger predator, and it has no way of knowing if there are any about.  And with no information on hunting spots in this new area, it could die of starvation.  So there is much to fear for a cat being moved to a new location, and most cats act that way.